# react-perfect-scrollbar not working properly in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, react-perfect-scrollbar

I have used react-perfect-scrollbar in my react app. The version is:- `"react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8"`,

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
```

And this is how I used the PerfectScrollbar wrapper

```
<PerfectScrollbar>
// children goes here //
</PerfectScrollbar>
```

The scrollbar is showing up in google chrome, but not in firefox. I changed the code and style height like this:-

```
<PerfectScrollbar style={{height: 'auto'}}>
</PerfectScrollbar>
```

This was working in `Firefox` in my home PC (I don't remember the version), but in my office PC this too, doesn't work in `Firefox` (version is 121). If I put

`style={{height: 500}}`

or anything else, I can see the scrollbar in `Firefox` (version is 121).

The element wrapped inside `<PrefectScrollbar>` is a `ul` `li` menu which can be of any length/height. So I can't put a specific height as well. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: check to make sure no other styles in your app are messing with the CSS of. Browser-specific styles can sometimes create problems like this.